# How can I set a custom font in my app, while respecting the user's system font settings?

Tags: android, fonts

Some hardware manufacturers (e.g. Samsung) allow the user to set a custom font at a system level. This affects all default `TextView` instances (in system apps or installed apps):

[image: screenshot of samsung font style page, radio group shows a list of font styles, with default selected]

I want to customize the font for my `TextView` with a custom font in my app, but also respect the user's setting.

i.e. if the user has chosen "Default" above, then I want my `TextView` to use *my* custom font, but if they've selected any of the others, then I want my `TextView` to use whatever they've selected.

Using `textView.typeface == Typeface.DEFAULT` seems to return `true` regardless of the user's system setting. Is there a way to differentiate between "Default" and any of these custom settings, even if it's manufacturer specific?

Comment: I don't need to prevent the custom font in samsung devices. I need to keep it as per user's choice but set to Roboto n other devices .Please help .I looked at that question doesn't really help

Comment: Have you tried that it's not working? For me, this was authomatically

Comment: it's working in the sense that it's showing custom font when I use typeface.DEFAULT but I need to use Roboto as shown above in all other cases . In short all I need to do is to check whether the device has custom font sets and based on that return default or return roboto .

Comment: It doesn't have an answer there guys . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way to set fonts into textviews

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"));
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: I know that . I have done that . I need to check if custom fonts are set by user in devices like samsung and if yes switch to typeface.DEFAULT . My question was how I test that condition ?